# @bot.event causing commands to not respond

Tags: google-api, discord, discord.py, google-api-python-client

I recenlty added a code from google api serve=ive and it's causing my entire script to not reponding except for the event :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
        analyze_request = {'comment': { 'text': msg.content }, 'requestedAttributes': {'TOXICITY': {}}}
        response = service.comments().analyze(body=analyze_request).execute()
        spanScore = response['attributeScores']['TOXICITY']['spanScores']
        value = spanScore[0]['score']['value']
        print(value * 100)
        toxicity = value * 100
        if toxicity > 95:
            await msg.author.kick(reason = "Toxic messages")
            await msg.author.send('You were kicked because you sent toxic message(s)')
            await msg.send(f"{msg.author}, has been kicked for being toxic !")
        elif toxicity > 70 and toxicity < 94:
            await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention}, please watch your language")
```

Thanks for futur anwsers

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the commands, add the following at the end of your `on_message` event:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

More information regarding this topic on the [`documentation`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)